# Stack Exchange Site "Where to ask this?" Guidance

Tags: discussion, questions, stack-exchange, scope

A common response to many questions on Stack Exchange sites is along the lines of, "This question belongs on [another.stackexchangesite.com]." Hopefully it's phrased nicely, etc., but that's appropriate feedback in order to keep the sites on-topic and effective.

However, it can be challenging, especially for newer users, to know *where* to ask their question, as there are so many different Stack Exchange sites, often with seemingly overlapping (or at least somewhat closely-related) purposes and scope definitions. Also, each site has a fairly specific definition explaining what is on-topic and what is not; however, for users who aren't experienced with many of the different SE sites, it's a lot to ask for them to read and become adequately familiar with every different scope definition that might apply to their questions or interests.

Is there some quick-and-easy way for users to quickly identify which site would be best for presenting their question? If not, would it be helpful to have a "sticky question" of sorts here on Meta SE, for example, that helps people quickly sort out where to go to ask their specific question?

Comment: I think that is described in https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info and there are some generic, most common asked ones captured in some meta posts for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on

Comment: Hm, that's a good point, I'd forgotten about that. However it might be nice to have that linked from the home page of Meta Stack Exchange, or perhaps even in the header/sidebar of every site. It's not easily discovered by users who don't already know it's there, and these are the users who need it most!

Comment: I don't believe there is a *quick and easy* way to find the right site. Finding the right venue is part of the research needed for a good question. I don't fancy having loads of lost souls dump their question here on MSE for us to sort out where it belongs which would happen if MSE would be prominent linked as a place where you can go with questions that deemed off-topic on a main site.

Comment: I wonder if we could have  "sibling" meta site whose only purpose is to locate good homes for lost questions?

Comment: @JasonBassford who do you expect to write the answers there?

Comment: @rene True, it might not be practical. Then again, I wouldn't put it past some people to be interested in providing that kind of help. I was thinking of the logic of it more than anything else.

Comment: @rene Again, I think a prominent link to the `site-recommendation` page you referenced could be valuable. And/or the question you reference, as well.

Comment: @rene Also, I fully appreciate the point about "finding the right venue" being an important part of one's research; however, new users (say, to StackOverflow) may not even be aware that other sites DO exist, let alone where to find them to begin to "research" their options.

A prominent link seems the most straightforward solution to all these concerns, imho.

Answer (score 3):

At the GIS Stack Exchange we have created a Meta GIS SE post that attempts to help redirect questions that are off-topic (or not clearly on-topic) to sites where they are likely to be well received.

[Other places for help when off-topic (or not clearly on-topic) for GIS SE?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/401/115)

The challenge is helping new and existing users to review it before posting such questions. At the moment the best we can do is to occasionally set it to be featured in the sidebar and to have it permanently linked to from the first page of the Help Center.

At least two other sites do something similar (see [comment by @ale](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311412/stack-exchange-site-where-to-ask-this-guidance/311413?noredirect=1#comment1018079_311413)) and these are:

- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions)
- [Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/855/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions)

(click their names to see their Meta post)